# Why would few .png images not be created using this script?

Tags: php, image, png, gd, libpng

**Edit**

ok, I figured it was actually a JFIF jpg image, saved as .png. Changing the script as follows works:

```
// load image and get image size
// switch ($ext) {
//   case 'jpg':
//   case 'jpeg':
//     $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($uri_source);
//     break;
//   case 'png':
//     $img = imagecreatefrompng($uri_source);
//     break;
//   case 'gif':
//     $img = imagecreatefromgif($uri_source);
//     break;
// }

if (!$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($uri_source)) {
  if (!$img = imagecreatefrompng($uri_source)) {
    if (!$img = imagecreatefromgif($uri_source)) {
      die($index);
    }
  }
}
```

---

I am writing a little script which creates a thumbnail for every n images there is within a folder. Everything works fine so far, except the weird fact that a few thumbnails wont be generated. They all are .pngs, but many other .png files do work, so I guess its not the script itself. Any clues?

```
$dir = opendir($path_source);
while (false !== ($fname = readdir($dir)) && $index < $limit ) {
  $info = pathinfo($path_source . $fname);

  if ( isset($info['extension']) && preg_match('~(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)~', strtolower($info['extension'])) ) {
    $uri_source = $path_source . $fname;
    $uri_dest = $path_dest . $fname;


    if (!file_exists($path_dest . $fname)) {
      $ext = strtolower($info['extension']);
      // load image and get image size
      switch ($ext) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
          $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($uri_source);
          break;
        case 'png':
          $img = imagecreatefrompng($uri_source);
          break;
        case 'gif':
          $img = imagecreatefromgif($uri_source);
          break;
      }

      $width = imagesx( $img );
      $height = imagesy( $img );

      $thumb_height = floor( $height * ( $thumb_width / $width ) );

      $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );

      imagecopyresampled( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $width, $height );

      // save thumbnail into a file
      // switch ($ext) {
      //   case 'jpg':
      //   case 'jpeg':
      //     imagejpeg( $tmp_img, $uri_dest );
      //     break;
      //   case 'png':
      //     imagesavealpha($tmp_img, true);
      //     imagealphablending($tmp_img, true);
      //     imagepng( $tmp_img, $uri_dest );
      //     break;
      //   case 'gif':
      //     imagegif( $tmp_img, $uri_dest );
      //     break;
      // }

      // trying to force a jpg thumb, still doesnt work

      $uri_dest = str_replace('.png', '.jpg', $uri_dest);
      imagejpeg( $tmp_img, $uri_dest );
      imagedestroy($tmp_img);
    }

    $thumbs[] = '<a href="' . $uri_source . '" ' . $link_attributes . '><img ' . $img_attributes . ' src="' . $uri_dest . '" class="thumb" /></a>';

    $index++;
  }


}
closedir($dir);
```

on a win machine, using mamp.

i checked the error log, sometimes this appears:

> imagecreatefrompng(): 'path/to/file.png' is not a valid PNG file

resulting in

> imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given imagesy()
>   expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given Division by zero
>   imagecreatetruecolor(): Invalid image dimensions imagecopyresampled()
>   expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given imagejpeg() expects
>   parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given imagedestroy() expects
>   parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

but why does the file seem not to be a valid png? i am pretty sure it is.

Comment: Just a tip.  You can do: `$img = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($uri_source));`.  This will make GD figure out what type of image it is automagically.

Comment: Please do not edit your answer into the question. You are allowed and even *encouraged* to submit it as a proper answer. As it is, your question is no longer a *question*.